# Add data to last row of CSV using VBScript

Tags: csv, vbscript

I am trying to append a CSV's last row and allow it to be read by a C# user control.

The reason we have to do that way is because the data become available at two different times.

It works fine except for the following:

1. It generates an empty line after appending.
2. After repeating it for 3-4 steps it deletes the whole file.

The code is below:

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objInFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("R:\cat3_data.csv", 1)

strContents = objInFile.ReadAll
objInFile.Close

arrRows = Split(strContents, vbNewLine)
MsgBox UBound(arrRows)
arrRows(UBound(arrRows) - 1) = arrRows(UBound(arrRows) - 1) & "," & "Hi" & _ 
    "," & "Hi" & "," & "Hi" & "," & "Hi" & "," & "Hi"
strContents = Join(arrRows, vbNewLine)

Set objOutFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("R:\cat3_data.csv", 2)
objOutFile.WriteLine strContents
objOutFile.Close
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

Comment: Two things that I found: 1) `strContents = join(arrRows, vbNewLine)` creates the empty line when adding new data. Seeing as this is a CSV, which is comma delimited, it seems it would make sense to use a comma instead of `vbNewline`, and 2) the `2` in `set objOutFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("R:\cat3_data.csv", 2)` is "writing" to the file. If you want to "append", you need to use an `8` instead.

Comment: but appending adds entire rows again.The basic idea is to change the final 5 values in the last row of csv

Comment: What are you changing them to besides 5 Hi's? In your first three sentences, you mentioned "append" twice, isn't that what you're trying to do is append 5 Hi's to the next row without an empty row after?

Comment: I guess i did not explain properly. the way it works is there a VBScript A.vbs which captures date for 12/17 columns and adds them to a csv CSVA.csv. then after 2-3 seconds another VBScript B.vbs capture data for rest of the columns and now it has to access CSVA.csv and add these to the respective columns in the last row. The code I have shown here is part of that B.vbs. Those Hi's are place holders. After this A.vbs will again acces the file to writein new row of data and B.vbs has to add more data to it and this continues on.

Comment: `WriteLine` automatically appends a newline to the written text. Use `Write` to avoid this. The concatenation doesn't change the values in the last row (second-last, actually), but appends the additional values to that line (`a,b,c` -> `a,b,c,d,e,f`). Please clarify what you actually want to achieve (sample input and output would help). As for the file getting deleted, there's nothing in the code you posted that would do this.

Comment: The workflow goes like this;
at t=0
CSV file is populated with 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12 and a header
at t=2
append the following to the values 13,14,15,16,17
at t=10
add new row a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l
at t=12
add these values to the last row m,n,o,p,q,r

so the outputs at rspective times will be:
t = 0
header
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12

t=2
header
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17

t=10
header
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r


t=12
header
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17
a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l